# QtQuick2 ComboBox with sections

Tags: qt, combobox, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I would like to have the same section functionality in a ComboBox like in the ListView ([Example of sectioned ListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#section-prop)).

But I cannot find anything like this in the ComboBox.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Qt Quick Controls 1 or 2 ?

Comment: I am working only with 2.0 right now, I am not sure if I can mix 1.0 and 2.0

Comment: Ok, I added the tag. You can mix them if you import as : `import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as QQC1` and later use it like that : `QQC1.ComboBox`. It doesn't matter here cause it's easier to do what you want with QQC2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to have the same section functionality as a `ListView` in a `ComboBox`, you can simply include a `ListView` in your `ComboBox`.

You can customize basically all the Qt Quick Controls 2, here is an example for `ComboBox` : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-combobox

In your case you need to customize the `popup` property to include a `ListView` with sections enabled.

I wrote an example :

```
ComboBox {
    id: control
    width: 200
    model : ["Albert Dupontel","Antoine Griezmann","Peter Sagan","Rodney Mullen","Serena Williams"]
    popup: Popup {
        y: control.height
        width: control.width
        implicitHeight: Math.min(contentItem.implicitHeight, 300)
        padding: 0

        contentItem: ListView {
            clip: true
            implicitHeight: contentHeight
            model: control.popup.visible ? control.delegateModel : null
            currentIndex: control.highlightedIndex
            section.property: "modelData"
            section.criteria: ViewSection.FirstCharacter
            section.delegate: Label {
                x: 10
                text: section
            }

            ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
        }
    }
}
```

It renders like that : [image: ComboBox with section]